# GORM deleted_at" IS NULL

Tags: postgresql, go, grails-orm

I just started learning GORM and currently trying to fetch data from one to many tables.
I have two tables :users and documents. A user can have multiple documents . When i try fetching documents I keep getting the error

```
documents: unsupported relations for schema User
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL
```

Below is the code where I attempt to fetch data

```
type User struct {

    
    gorm.Model
    Name         string 
    Email         string    
    Password  string    
    Documents []Document
}

type Document struct {
    
    gorm.Model
    Name         string 
    DateCreated         string  
    UserID uint 
    
}
```

Function to fetch data

```
func GetAll(db *gorm.DB) ([]models.User, error) {
    var users []models.User
   // err := db.Model(&models.User{}).Preload("documents").Find(&users).Error
    err:=db.Preload("documents").Find(&[]models.User{}).Error
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Println("got users")
    return users, err
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to your Table is not contain the relevant field "deleted_at" as you used the gorm.Model.
If you used gorm.Model, it will automatically integrate 4 fields as

```
 ID: an auto-incrementing integer primary key
CreatedAt: a timestamp of when the record was created
UpdatedAt: a timestamp of when the record was last updated
DeletedAt: a soft delete timestamp used to mark the record as deleted instead of    actually deleting it from the database.
```

If you do not need this, you can simply use

```
db.Unscoped().
Ex:
db.Unscoped().Where("param = ?", "param").Find(&YourStruct)
```

Then it will fix the issue.

[I know you already fix this issue, but i added this for any other who is facing for similar situations]